# Human Asset Development or Human Assets Development

Tags: grammatical-number, business-language, noun-phrases

Human Assets Development
or
Human Asset Development

The second one has no "s" at the end of asset. Which is more natural, and is there a rule for this (for example, use a singular noun (human asset) when the noun is used in a phrase (human asset development)?

Comment: There are few rules for things like this, they're all ideosyncratic.

Comment: Plural seems more natural, since an organization usually has more than one human asset.

Comment: I've rarely heard the phrase "Human Assets" -- more common is "Human Resources". This is always plural in my experience.

Comment: Thank you everyone for commenting. Edit: I found a related Wikipedia article that uses the singular.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_asset_management

Comment: It's just business jargon, and doesn't mean anything,  Ask your boss. If you're the boss, you can do it whatever way you like.

Comment: Either can be better, depending on usage.  The meanings aren't the same.

Comment: I suggest that very broadly 'Human Asset Development' would describe a general concept, while '(the) Development of Human Assets' might refer to a specific process.

'Our organization takes the idea of human asset development seriously. We see the development of (our) human assets as important.'